# How to use a string with backslashes in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, backslash

I want to maintain a variable with a string which contains backslashes and don't want to alter that. When I try to use the string, it gets extra backslashes as escape characters. I tried with 'r' ( raw ) modifier - but it didn't help.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = r'\abc'
>>> s
'\\abc'
```

I have a test where I am trying to have an array of possible values with ''. But when I take them out, it doesn't come as expected:

```
>>> value =  [r'"\1"', r'"\\1"', r'"\\\1"' ]
>>> for val in value:
...   print value
...
['"\\1"', '"\\\\1"', '"\\\\\\1"']
['"\\1"', '"\\\\1"', '"\\\\\\1"']
['"\\1"', '"\\\\1"', '"\\\\\\1"']
```

How do I do this?

---

<sub>I saw questions regarding the problem with backslash related issues in Python. But I couldn't get a specific answer for the problem that I am hitting.</sub>

Comment: Console outputs repr(s). Thus you get extra `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is **not altered**. Use the *print* statement to print the actual variable contents.

In the second example, you just print the whole list, not the items present inside the list.

```
>>> s = r'\abc'
>>> print s
\abc
>>> value =  [r'"\1"', r'"\\1"', r'"\\\1"' ]
>>> for val in value:
        print val


"\1"
"\\1"
"\\\1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the *representation* of the strings as if they were normal strings, which they are not.

When you use raw string literals, then print the string. Any escape character like `\` is itself escaped in the representation, leading to a multiplication of `\` symbols. Your strings are fine.

Comment: @Joel, I'm not sure if you're able to yet, but higher-rep users can click on the score of a question or answer and see the number of votes in each direction. Both of the answers to this question got **2** downvotes within a minute or two of being posted. Somebody and their sock puppet was not feeling charitable...

Answer (score 0):

IDK if this helps your *specific* problem, but if r\ isn't working, you can always put two backslashes to force python to interpret it literally. Instead of "r\abc", use "\abc". I had to do this for one of my class tests as well, and it helped me a lot to use \ because it works reliably, whereas r\ has some parameters to keep in mind.